# How to calculate field in R based on the formula specified in excel

Tags: r, calculation

I want R to read in an Excel containing formula and produce its output.
Say for example if I provide the following as input:

```
a   b   c
2   5   =a+b
3   2   =a+b
3   3   =a+b
6   4   =a+b
4   2   =a+b
```

I should get this output:

```
    a   b   c
    2   5   7
    3   2   5
    3   3   6
    6   4   10
    4   2   6
```

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to remove the `=` using `sub` and evaluate the first element (as it is the same for all the rows)

```
df1$c <- with(df1, eval(parse(text= sub("=", "", c[1]))))
df1$c
#[1]  7  5  6 10  6
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(a = c(2L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 4L), b = c(5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
 2L), c = c("=a+b", "=a+b", "=a+b", "=a+b", "=a+b")), .Names = c("a", 
 "b", "c"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```